# LD_LIBRARY_PATH is ignored by GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc

according to docs, GCC looks paths in LD_LIBRARY_PATH for linking shared library BUT it seems in my case it is ignored!

`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -->`:/home/mehrdad/usr/lib`  (so `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set currectly)

i have `libfoo.so` in "`/home/mehrdad/usr/lib`" BUT :
`gcc main.c -lfoo`  returns error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

so what is the problem??? is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` deprecated???!

but i can successfully link with explicit command :

```
gcc main.c -L/home/mehrdad/usr/lib -lfoo
```

and also I can successfully execute the a.out by just:

```
./a.out
```

it seems LD_LIBRARY_PATH is respected by OS library loader BUT NOT GCC!

my environment :
OS       : CentOs 7
compiler : gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)

Comment: Roughly, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used when your executable (really the dynamic linker) looks up the libraries at runtime, that is when you start the program. At compilation time, library paths should be set with the `-L` option.

Comment: "*according to docs, GCC looks paths in LD_LIBRARY_PATH for linking shared library*" Can you link to those docs? (Perhaps you are confusing `LIBRARY_PATH` with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Perhaps your docs are.)

Comment: thank you guys!  i honestly only heard about LD_LIBRARY_PATH !

Comment: so 'LIBRARY_PATH' is not for compile-time linking phase??! only for run-time linking?

Comment: You're confusing them again.

Comment: ooh! LD_LIBRARY_PATH -->LD = loader!!!   I got it!     thank you!

Comment: The behavior really depends on the OS. Some (like solaris) take it into account to search for libraries, others (glibc) ignore it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was wrong! thanks to `Alexandre C` and  `David Schwartz`!

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is only for loader(runtime).

`LIBRARY_PATH` is what I need according to the docs:

> The value of LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated list of directories,
>   much like PATH. When configured as a native compiler, GCC tries the
>   directories thus specified when searching for special linker files, if
>   it cannot find them using GCC_EXEC_PREFIX. Linking using GCC also uses
>   these directories when searching for ordinary libraries for the -l
>   option (but directories specified with -L come first).